# Updating Data On PARENT Via Custom Button

Tags: administration, custom-button, master-detail

This is *loosely related* to a recent question:  [Standard Button CODE Available?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11129/standard-button-code-available)

Does anyone know of any examples/tutorials on creating a **custom button which will set values into the PARENT record** of the record/object that the button is clicked from?

**Example**:   Opportunity has a Custom Object called Company Form.  When Credit Card data is submitted via a Company Form and approved by various parties, they'd like a button to copy the CCard data into similarly named fields on the Parent (Opportunity).

So CreditCard_Name__c would be copied to the Opportunity's CCard_Name__c field as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom JS button  and it would look something like this-

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/8.0/connection.js")}

var connection = sforce.connection;

var oppty = "{!Company_forms__c.OpportunityId__c}";

if (oppty  != "")
{
    var opp = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
    opp.Id = oppty ;
    opp.CCard_Name__c = "{!Company_forms__c.CreditCard_Name__c}";

    connection.update([opp]);
    alert("Done.");
}
else
{
    alert("There is no Opportunity to update.");
}
```

Here is a good reference:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm

Answer (score 0):

Is there really a need for a button? You could accomplish this with workflow:

1. Create a WF with rule, Company Form -> Status = "Approved"
2. Create Field Updates with Cross Object WF that would copy these values from the Company Form to the Account